# How to copy group layer shape files to geodatabase retaining layer order using Model builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have set of shapefiles that represent cadastar plan. Correct order of layers look like this in TOC.

[image: shape file in correct order]

I would like to import same structure to existing geodatabase katastar.gdb so I have something like this:

[image]

Can this be done with ModelBuilder? Feature class to geodatabase (multiple) does not accept group layer? I probably need to iterate somehow sublayers in group layer and then import one by one. But how to do that?

Comment: Rather than select the grouplayer can you not select the individual layers then drag 'n' drop them all into the featureclass to geodatabase tool?

Comment: Of course I can, but then I have to rearrange them inside geodatabase. I would like to automate this process via model builder because I have 100+ layer groups to convert to gdb...

Comment: The order you see featureclassses in a geodatabase will be based upon their name. Unless you deliberately use a naming convention that places them in order you'll get what arcmap will give you. Out of curiosity why would the order of tables shown in the geodatabase matter?

Comment: Maybe order is whorng term. Sorry, english is not my native language. I'm trying to retain hierarchy iniside geodatabase same as in TOC. I need feature dataset to corresponde to layer group, and feature class inside feature dataset to be as in toc. To simplify, I want to transfer from shape to geodatabase and retain group hierarchy.

Comment: ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comments above:

The issue with trying to simulate the hierarchy in a geodatabase is that to be in a *FeatureDataset* all *FeatureClass* must be in the same coordinate system and spatial extent defined by the *FeatureDataset*.

Layers in a *Group Layer* can be in completely different coordinate systems and extents. So if you wanted to group all the same layers in your *Group Layer* into a single *FeatureDataset* you would need to project them and ensure they are within the same spatial extent. By spatial extent I mean you could be using a European wide coordinate system but if the FeatureDataset extent has been set to Poland then the UK is not in it (brexit pun! :) )

That could be a lot of work. A possible solution is kind of what you have done, the *FeatureClass* is prefixed with your *Group Layer* name, e.g.kn_Blato_1000_. Or you could have 1 geodatabase for 1 grouplayer?

I don't think there are any geo-processing tools that can extract out the grouplayer name from a layer in an mxd, you would need to run this in python. Have a look at the help file for layer object in `arcpy.mapping` module to access the property `longName`.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. You are right about projection. All my shapefiles are in same projection so there is no problem with that, but I have to have that always on my mind. I made small python to create FeatureDataset inside existing geodatabase from the list of Group layer names. I think you have a great idea. With combination of longName and listLayers command maybe I could get where I want. I'll give it a try.